# Most efficient way of getting the N last element of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq

For a project, I will have to take very often the N last element of an array containing a lot of data.

I tried to make

```
myArray.Skip(myArray.Length - toTake).Take(toTake)
```

But I found it slow.

I compared it to this:

```
public static int[] TakeLast(this int[] inputArray, int count)
{
    int[] returnArray = new int[count];
    int startIndex = Math.Max(inputArray.Count() - count, 0);
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* itemArrayPtr = &(inputArray[startIndex]))
        {
            fixed (int* arrayPtr = &(returnArray[0]))
            {
                int* itemValuePtr = itemArrayPtr;
                int* valuePtr = arrayPtr;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    *valuePtr++ = *itemValuePtr++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

This works well be this cannot be generic(I wish this could work for any primitive type(int, float, double, ...).

Is there a way to achieve a comparable performance having a generic/linq/... method? I don't need to make it works on IEnumerable, Array is enough for me.

**EDIT**
I'm currently testing all methods you gave me, for now it's the Array.Copy which seems to be the faster:

```
Generating array for 100000000 elements.
SkipTake: 00:00:00.3009047
Unsafe: 00:00:00.0006289
Array.Copy: 00:00:00.0000012
Buffer.BlockCopy: 00:00:00.0001860
Reverse Linq: 00:00:00.2201143
Finished
```

Comment: `new T[count]` followed by `Array.Copy`? BTW, a short program that demonstrates in what way `Enumerable.Skip` / `Enumerable.Take` are slow would be great, that would make it possible to actually test suggested alternatives, instead of mainly guessing.

Comment: Yes, I would have thought that Array.Copy() would be as fast as doing pointer arithmetic, since it probably uses memcpy equivalent in implementation.

Comment: I don't think it'd make a noticeable difference, but your call to `Take()` is unnecessary.  Does performance improve much if you just use `myArray.Skip(myArray.Length - toTake)`?

Comment: @hvd: Please post this as answer. Amazing how fast it is

Comment: @BACON Good point, I tested it without the `Take()` but still seems slow

Comment: @J4N Sure, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments:

```
public static T[] TakeLast<T>(this T[] inputArray, int count)
{
    var result = new T[count];
    Array.Copy(inputArray, inputArray.Length - count, result, 0, count);
    return result;
}
```

seems to perform well. It's worth pointing out that depending on the specific needs, it may be possible to avoid the new array altogether, and iterate over the original `inputArray`. You can't copy faster than not copy at all. :)

Comment: +1 My tests show this is the best solution, IMO. Maybe you should add `count = Math.Min(count, inputArray.Length);` at the start.

Comment: Thank you, the better solution after all my tests. How would you avoid the new array? (in my case I can make a direct reference to the base array, neither the original or the destination will be changed, read only operation)

Comment: @J4N You could create a custom `IEnumerable<T>` that holds a reference to the original array, and an index into that array. It would be similar to how `Enumerable.Skip` works, but firstly, since you know you're dealing with an array, you can access the array elements by index, and secondly, you have enough extra information to avoid unnecessary boxing operations. Whether that performs better than copying the data depends on the data involved.

Comment: You could also use [`ArraySegment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which implements `IEnumerable<T>` (but I think you need .Net 4.5 for the IEnumerable feature)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ha, I didn't know that existed. That's pretty much what I was suggesting, the only difference would be that depending on the data, it might be beneficial to add a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns a value type. :)

Comment: Neither do I. But in my case, I've to return an array an not an IEnumerable. but the original solution speed is fair enough ;) Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? Should be fairly fast:

```
public static class ArrayExt
{
    public static T[] TakeLast<T>(this T[] inputArray, int count) where T: struct
    {
        count = Math.Min(count, inputArray.Length);
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

        T[] result = new T[count];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(inputArray, (inputArray.Length-count)*size, result, 0, count*size);

        return result;
    }
}
```

(I think this is a bit faster than Array.Copy() for primitive types. But I'm not going to take that for granted - be back in 5 mins with some timings. ;)

---

[EDIT] Timings show that Array.Copy() a similar speed, but results vary from run to run and depending on the array size.

Here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10000;
            var array = Enumerable.Range(0, ARRAY_SIZE).Select(x => x).ToArray();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            const int COUNT = 100000;

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            {
                sw.Restart();

                for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; ++j)
                    array.TakeLastViaArrayCopy(ARRAY_SIZE/2);

                Console.WriteLine("TakeLastViaArrayCopy took " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();

                for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; ++j)
                    array.TakeLastViaBlockCopy(ARRAY_SIZE/2);

                Console.WriteLine("TakeLastViaBlockCopy took " + sw.Elapsed);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }

    public static class ArrayExt
    {
        public static T[] TakeLastViaBlockCopy<T>(this T[] inputArray, int count) where T: struct
        {
            count = Math.Min(count, inputArray.Length);
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

            T[] result = new T[count];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(inputArray, (inputArray.Length-count)*size, result, 0, count*size);

            return result;
        }

        public static T[] TakeLastViaArrayCopy<T>(this T[] inputArray, int count) where T: struct
        {
            count = Math.Min(count, inputArray.Length);

            T[] result = new T[count];
            Array.Copy(inputArray, inputArray.Length-count, result, 0, count);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Results (release build as usual):

```
TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.3028503
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.3052196

TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.2969425
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.3000117

TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.2906120
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.2987753

TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.2954674
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.3005010

TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.2944490
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.3006893

TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.3041998
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.2920206

TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.3115137
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.2996884

TakeLastViaArrayCopy took 00:00:00.2906820
TakeLastViaBlockCopy took 00:00:00.2985933
```

`Array.Copy()` is simpler, so that's the one to use.

Comment: Nice, but why would this be faster than Array.Copy? For now my tests doesn't show it faster.

Comment: @J4N It's not faster - I just tried it. Array.Copy() is faster. I'll put a disclaimer in my answer - you need to post your Array.Copy() answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to reward hvc which comes with this solution. So if he doesn't post it I will.

Comment: @J4N Oh sorry, yes I meant that hvd should post it (I said "you" by mistake)

Answer (score 2):

Since **C#8** you can use a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) like so.

```cs
var lastN = array[^n..];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray.Reverse().Take(toTake).Reverse();
```

Comment: Seems to be a small bit faster than Skip.Take, but still take a lot of time